# iText: Display signaturedetails on visible signature

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, signing

In the current project, I am signing pdf-documents with itext and java. I am also able to create a visible signature. But now I need to customize the visible signature. The visible signature have to contain the signer's name, email, reason, and the signing date. Can I somehow read this information from the certificate to display them on the visible stamp? I tried with the PdfTemplates but I didn't find a way to refrence to the certificate data. I only were able to set static text in the visible signature.

In other words: Is it possible to choose which certificate details are displayed on the visible stamp, without setting explicite text in the pdftemplates (use reference to certificatedetails like timestamp, DN, what ever instead static text)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no: You can freely set the text in the signature visualization using `PdfSignatureAppearance.setLayer2Text()` (you can even design the whole appearance on `PdfSignatureAppearance.getLayer(2)`) but no evaluation of variables will take place.

So you have to inspect the certificate yourself and extract the information to put into that string you are going to set with `setLayer2Text`. For some details you may use iText helper classes, e.g. the `CertificateInfo` methods `getIssuerFields()` or `getSubjectFields()`; for others you will need your own methods. But you can use the code of those methods as a template for the methods you need to implement.